# How to remove span tags using grep in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, html

```
<span class="cur_name">This is a sentence </span>
```

I wanted to just get the "This is a sentence" part and remove the span tags using grep. How do i do this??

I don't wanna use awk|sed and anything else because I'm not familiar with it. Thank you!

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a terrible idea. You shouldn't use a hammer to make holes just because you don't know how power drills work.

That said:

```
echo '<span class="cur_name">This is a sentence </span>' | \
    grep -o '>[^<]*<' | grep -o '[^<>]*'
```

Comment: + is probably better than *

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should heed the advice given by @glenn jackmann and @that other guy: don't  parse HTML with regexes in particular, use the right tool for the job in general.

---

On Linux, you can take advantage of using `grep` with PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), using the `-P` option.

This allows you to use so-called *look-around assertions* to provide context for your desired match without including that context in the output.

**Simplest** case (just **matching between `>` and `<`**):

```
echo '<span class="cur_name">This is a sentence </span>' |
 grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<]*(?=<)'
```

- `(?<=>)`, a look-*behind* assertion - `(?<=...)` -, matches `>` without including it in the match.
- `(?=<)`, a look-*ahead* assertion - `(?=...)` -, matches `<` without including it in the match.

If you want to **match the surrounding tags flexibly, by type**:

Look-*behind* assertions (`(?<=...)`) are limited in that they must be of *fixed length*.
Thus, if you wanted to match *any* opening `<span>` tag, regardless of attributes, you could use the `\K` feature, which simply drops the part of the match to the left of it:

```
echo '<span class="cur_name">This is a sentence </span>' |
  grep -Po '<span(\s+[^>]*)?>\K[^<]*(?=</span>)'
```

---

Finally, to give you a sense of how easy HTML/XML parsing can be with the right tools, here's a solution based on the [multi-platform web-scraping CLI **xidel**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
echo '<span class="cur_name">This is a sentence </span>' |
  xidel -e '/span' -
```

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu grep

```
grep -Po '<span[^>]*>\K[^<]*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/, " ");$1=$1}1' file
This is a sentence
```

But the shortest and possible best solution would be `sed`

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' file
This is a sentence
```

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' t
This is a sentence
```